ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource - SpringData Jpa
I've got deadlock in my SpringDataJpa - "ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource".
The problem appears when then are a large number of queries.
Is sth wrong with given piece of code?
***Maximum number of cars to delete never exceed 10
****I can't use batch delete or raw delete query, becauase I use envers and entites that would be deleted must be loaded into the application context
@Transactional
public Result replaceCarWithGivenBrand(Request request) {

    List<Car> cars = repository.findCarsByBrand(request.getBrand());
    
    deleteOldCars(cars);
    mapAndSaveNewCar(request);
    return Result.UPDATED;
}

private void deleteOldCars(List<Car> cars) {
    repository.deleteAll(cars);
    entityManager.flush();
}

private void mapAndSaveNewCar(Request request) {
    List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
    repository.saveAll(cars);
}

I'd like avoid problem with deadlocks.

You need to attach a stack trace of the error to your question.

You should look in the alert.log of the server, the deadlock detected should be reported along with a reference to a trace file containing more information, including the SQL statements concerned.

It would be difficult to comment without seeing the domain objects for both Car and Brands. But I don't understand why you have to explicitly the flush on deletion of cars. During transaction close, Hibernate will issue flush and commit.
